# How to handle nested relation in laravel resource - 2

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

So I've been trying to get a second level relation out of my "CategoryResource" but it's not working, here is some of my code :

First, My model :

```
public function children()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
public function sub_children()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

and then the "CategoryResource" :

```
    $data = [

        'id' => $this->id,

        'parent_id' => $this->parent_id,
        'order' => $this->order,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'slug' => $this->slug,

        'childs' => CategoryResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('children') && $this->whenLoaded('children')),

        'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,

        'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,

    ];
```

My Controller

```
    return CategoryResource::collection(Category::where('parent_id',null)->with('children.sub_children')->get());
```

Is there anyway i can retrieve my nested relation through laravel resource ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `with` function in the relationship. It would be something like this:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id')
                ->with('children');
}
```

It is going to load the children and then "subChildren" as relations of the first object.

So, you are going to load it as:

```
$children = $originalObject->children;
foreach ($children as $c) {
    $subChildren = $c->children;
}
```

Check if this works for your problem.